# pyspark - Chaining a .orderBy to a .read method

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say you have something like the following code:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('s3://somebucket/some_parquet_file')
```

How would you chain an order by on to that object?

```
df = df.orderBy(df.some_col)
```

To make it something like:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('s3://somebucket/some_parquet_file').orderBy(?.some_col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the column name as a [string or a list of strings](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy):

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('s3://somebucket/some_parquet_file').orderBy("some_col")
```